# Expanding date ranges with associated data with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a huge amount of data that I need to process to allow for a data analysis. 
Currently, the data is in [image: this form], and my goal is to use VBA to produce [image: this].

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Michael S, are you able to show us what you've tried so far in VBA or what exactly you're having a problem with?

Comment: Why not just use filters. Highlight the first row and then in the Excel Data tab select filter

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Should work for your example...

```
Sub Dates()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RowIns As Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

Cont:

    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then

        GoTo Cont2

    End If

    RowIns = Cells(i, 4).Value - Cells(i, 3).Value

    If RowIns <= 0 Then

        i = i + 1

        GoTo Cont

    End If

    Rows(i + 1 & ":" & RowIns + i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Range("C" & i).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C" & i & ":C" & RowIns + i), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & i & ":B" & RowIns + i), Type:=xlFillCopy

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    i = i + RowIns + 1

    GoTo Cont

Next

Cont2:

Columns(4).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try this out first thing in the morning. Best wishes.